# links format change "on clic"

Tags: css

i have an issue on my site, and i don't know where it comes from.

every link "change" ( comes bigger & change place ) when i click it.

on menu link, they still are clicable, but with link in page, it doesnt work at all.

exemple :

https://www.beprovence.fr/en/department/bouches-du-rhone-en

try to click on "aix en provence" to see what happen.

thanks in advance for your help

Comment: It comes from the css definition in `style.css` around line 125. There is a `.hotel-detail-booknow a, a:active` rule defined that gives the link its enormous size and blue colour. I would guess that it should be: `.hotel-detail-booknow a, .hotel-detail-booknow a:active`. The rule is applied to *all* clicked links, not just the ones within a `.hotel-detail-booknow` element.

Comment: ok, i see. so when adding style to link, we need to add .class before EVERY a type ? i was supposing that .class a, a:active will work only for .class ! so i made the change more than one time :D Let me update this to see if it works :)

Comment: Please allow me to enter my comment as an answer.

Comment: don't know how to do this :o

Comment: I have posted an answer. If you are satisfied that it actually solves your problem, please tick the check mark next to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It comes from the css definition in style.css around line 125. There is this rule:

```
.hotel-detail-booknow a, a:active
```

defined that gives the link its enormous size and blue colour. I would guess that it should be:

```
.hotel-detail-booknow a, .hotel-detail-booknow a:active
```

In your case, the rule is applied to all clicked links, not just the ones within a `.hotel-detail-booknow` element.